# Tomcat SSL error after setting up certificate

Tags: tomcat, openssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-16.04

**This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response**.
    command used to generate cert and key pem file is as:

> **openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes**

```
  Tomcat connector is as:
```

> ```
> <Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
>     maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
>     enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
>     acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
>     clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
>   SSLEngine="on"
>   SSLCertificateFile="conf/cert.pem"
>   SSLCertificateKeyFile="conf/key.pem" />
> ```
>
> **> openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout
>   key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes**

Generating a 4096 bit RSA private key
..........................................................................

> writing new private key to 'key.pem'

---

---

*

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:IN 
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:MH 
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Pune 
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:softdel Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:iot 
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:localhost 
Email Address []:xyz@gmail.com
```

*

https://localhost:8443/

**[to see error screenshot click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9ks5.png)**

logs::

```
23-Jun-2018 13:29:35.460 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Jun-2018 13:29:35.483 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
23-Jun-2018 13:29:35.488 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
23-Jun-2018 13:29:35.490 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 5150 ms
23-Jun-2018 13:29:35.656 INFO [http-nio-8443-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:410)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

23-Jun-2018 13:29:35.659 INFO [http-nio-8443-exec-2] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:410)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

23-Jun-2018 13:29:35.720 INFO [http-nio-8443-exec-3] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:410)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2018-06-23 13:29:42 [http-nio-8443-exec-17] INFO  org.apache.jsp.index_jsp -  - Entered page login
```

Comment: does anyone have solution for the above problem?

Comment: I think your question reads much better now. If you don't get help here, you could try other sites, such as serverfault.com or maybe superuser.com

Comment: 1. Can you update your post to make it clear and obvious what your specific question is? Just adding a comment with _does anyone have solution_ is not really adequate. 2. [See this link for lots of suggestions](https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/how-to-fix-err-ssl-protocol-error) on how to resolve ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR with Chrome. 3. Is there a stack trace in Tomcat's log that you can show?

Comment: I edited question and inserted logs in it.

Comment: Answered on https://superuser.com/questions/1333373/tomcat-ssl-error-after-setting-up-certificate (which is explained more clearly and formatted better); this is not a programming issue.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 It would not be a programming issue if the OP was setting up a Production enviornment, but there are many questions on SO relating to implementing SSL in a localhost (development) environment, and it is a legitimate question here. That said, posting the same question on multiple SE sites is certainly not appropriate.